# Proof of Surjective and injective

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I run into a problem when I am trying to studying my review question, I am not sure how to prove the following question:

Suppose A,B,C are sets and f:A→B, g:C→A, f∘g:C→B. Are they true or flase. if true give a proof and if false. give a counterexample.

a) If f and g are both onto (surjective), then f∘g is injective 
b) If f∘g and g are both bijective, then f is bijective.

How will you prove that. Any help will be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: There is a mistake in the statement of both parts - neither makes sense.

Comment: sorry about that, i just fix the mistake, see if this make sense now

Answer (score 1):

Part (a) is false; take C to be a 2-point set and take A and B to be 1-point sets. There is only one possible definition for the maps involved, and you can see that injectivity is violated.

Part (b) is true because $f=(f\circ g)\circ g^{-1}$.